# How do I add drivers to a Print Server for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

How do I add Windows 7 drivers to a server which already hosts Windows XP drivers.

A lot of the Windows 7 drivers I'm trying to add have a different name than their Windows XP counterparts which is causing problems. Has anybody dealt with this?

Comment: Where are you adding the drivers, on the printer object or in the print server properties? How is the name causing problems?

Comment: What OS is on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your print server is a Windows platform.

The problem your have is that the name of each driver ( x86 and x64 ) must match, up to the driver version.

PCL5 and PCL 5 will not work.

We resolved that issue by upgrading our print server to 2008 r2 and reconfiguring/redeploying all our printers.

If you do not upgrade your print server and do not want to recreate youe print queue you will still have to change your current print drivers.

If your using Windows 2003 r2, you should download both x64 and x86 drivers for each printers model for 2003 r2 x64 and x86 ( With the arrival of Windows 7, there is now a bunch of Universal drivers, espically from HP)

If you use Windows 2008 r2 you should download both x64 and x86 with same name/driver version for Windows 7 ( they will work for XP).

1-Install the new print driver via the print queue. 
2-Try to install the other architecture driver via additional panel in the print queue.
2.1 
If it refuse to install it because your server can't find Ntprint, do this :
Go to a Windows 7 client and browse your print server for the print queue with new driver.
Windows 7 client should tell you that there is no compatible driver on the server and will ask you to install the driver from the client.
Select the Windows 7 architecture's driver and install .
Once the printer is installed, go to the printer option and select additionnal driver. Check the architecture missing either x32 or 64 and press ok. The Windows 7 client will ask you again to point to the correct driver. The Windows 7 client will then push the driver to your print server.

You will have to do this for each type of driver, hp pcl5, hp pcl 6, hp ps, canon etc.

I'll be more than happy to clear any part. Still learning